# Masquerade-PEB post Anniversary Update

Tags: powershell

Can anyone verify this [Masquerade-PEB](https://github.com/FuzzySecurity/PowerShell-Suite/blob/master/Masquerade-PEB.ps1) code still works in Windows 10 post anniversary update. I am attempting to use it to address PinToTaskbar in Windows 10, and it seems as if it no longer works post Anniversary update. :( But, I am getting some errors like `"Cannot convert null to type "System.IntPtr"."` that suggests maybe the code needs to be revised, not that it's totally non functional now.
This would all be so much easier if Microsoft just gave us a Group Policy mechanism to enable PinToTaskbar for specified programs. You know, like in house code used to manage machines. ;)

EDIT: I have been unable to recreate the specific error I was seeing. But the end result is that it doesn't make Pin to Taskbar possible. The code as implemented is

```
function PinToTaskbar {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
  ExecuteVerb $FilePath "taskbarpin" 
}

function UnpinFromTaskbar {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
  ExecuteVerb $FilePath "taskbarunpin" 
}

function PinToStartmenu {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
 ExecuteVerb $FilePath "startpin" 
}

function UnpinFromStartmenu {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
 ExecuteVerb $FilePath "startunpin" 
}

function ExecuteVerb {  
         param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$File,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Verb
         ) 

    $path = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($File) 
    $basePath = split-path $path -parent   #retrieve only the path File=C:\Windows\notepad.exe -> C:\Windows
    $targetFile = split-path $path -leaf    #retrieve only the file File=C:\Windows\notepad.exe -> notepad.exe

    $shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
    $folder = $shell.Namespace($basePath)        
    if ($folder)
    {
       $item = $folder.Parsename($targetFile) 

       if ($item)
       {
         $item.invokeverb($Verb)
         # "This method does not return a value." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
         # Therefore we have no chance to know if this was successful...
         write-host "Method [$Verb] executed for [$path]"       
       } 
       else
       {
         write-host "Target file [$targetFile] not found, aborting" 
       }             
    }
    else 
    {      
      write-host "Folder [$basePath] not found, aborting" 
    }

}

    function Masquerade-PEB {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Masquerade-PEB uses NtQueryInformationProcess to get a handle to powershell's
        PEB. From there itreplaces a number of UNICODE_STRING structs in memory to
        give powershell the appearance of a different process. Specifically, the
        function will overwrite powershell's "ImagePathName" & "CommandLine" in
        _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS and the "FullDllName" & "BaseDllName" in the
        _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY linked list.

        This can be useful as it would fool any Windows work-flows which rely solely
        on the Process Status API to check process identity. A practical example would
        be the IFileOperation COM Object which can perform an elevated file copy if it
        thinks powershell is really explorer.exe ;)!
        Notes:
          * Works on x32/64.

          * Most of these API's and structs are undocumented. I strongly recommend
            @rwfpl's terminus project as a reference guide!
              + http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/

          * Masquerade-PEB is basically a reimplementation of two functions in UACME
            by @hFireF0X. My code is quite different because,  unfortunately, I don't
            have access to all those c++ goodies and I could not get a callback for
            LdrEnumerateLoadedModules working!
              + supMasqueradeProcess: https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME/blob/master/Source/Akagi/sup.c#L504
              + supxLdrEnumModulesCallback: https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME/blob/master/Source/Akagi/sup.c#L477
    .DESCRIPTION
        Author: Ruben Boonen (@FuzzySec)
        License: BSD 3-Clause
        Required Dependencies: None
        Optional Dependencies: None
    .EXAMPLE
        C:\PS> Masquerade-PEB -BinPath "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"
    #>

        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
            [string]$BinPath
        )

        Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
        using System;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using System.Security.Principal;
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct UNICODE_STRING
        {
            public UInt16 Length;
            public UInt16 MaximumLength;
            public IntPtr Buffer;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct _LIST_ENTRY
        {
            public IntPtr Flink;
            public IntPtr Blink;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr ExitStatus;
            public IntPtr PebBaseAddress;
            public IntPtr AffinityMask;
            public IntPtr BasePriority;
            public UIntPtr UniqueProcessId;
            public IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
        }
        /// Partial _PEB
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 64)]
        public struct _PEB
        {
            [FieldOffset(12)]
            public IntPtr Ldr32;
            [FieldOffset(16)]
            public IntPtr ProcessParameters32;
            [FieldOffset(24)]
            public IntPtr Ldr64;
            [FieldOffset(28)]
            public IntPtr FastPebLock32;
            [FieldOffset(32)]
            public IntPtr ProcessParameters64;
            [FieldOffset(56)]
            public IntPtr FastPebLock64;
        }
        /// Partial _PEB_LDR_DATA
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct _PEB_LDR_DATA
        {
            public UInt32 Length;
            public Byte Initialized;
            public IntPtr SsHandle;
            public _LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
            public _LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
            public _LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
            public IntPtr EntryInProgress;
        }
        /// Partial _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY
        {
            public _LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderLinks;
            public _LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderLinks;
            public _LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderLinks;
            public IntPtr DllBase;
            public IntPtr EntryPoint;
            public UInt32 SizeOfImage;
            public UNICODE_STRING FullDllName;
            public UNICODE_STRING BaseDllName;
        }
        public static class Kernel32
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern UInt32 GetLastError();
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern Boolean VirtualProtectEx(
                IntPtr hProcess,
                IntPtr lpAddress,
                UInt32 dwSize,
                UInt32 flNewProtect,
                ref UInt32 lpflOldProtect);
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern Boolean WriteProcessMemory(
                IntPtr hProcess,
                IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
                IntPtr lpBuffer,
                UInt32 nSize,
                ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        }
        public static class Ntdll
        {
            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(
                IntPtr processHandle, 
                int processInformationClass,
                ref _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION processInformation,
                int processInformationLength,
                ref int returnLength);
            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern void RtlEnterCriticalSection(
                IntPtr lpCriticalSection);
            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            public static extern void RtlLeaveCriticalSection(
                IntPtr lpCriticalSection);
        }
    "@

        # Flag architecture $x32Architecture/!$x32Architecture
        if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
            $x32Architecture = 1
        }

        # Current Proc handle
        $ProcHandle = (Get-Process -Id ([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Id)).Handle

        # Helper function to overwrite UNICODE_STRING structs in memory
        function Emit-UNICODE_STRING {
            param(
                [IntPtr]$hProcess,
                [IntPtr]$lpBaseAddress,
                [UInt32]$dwSize,
                [String]$data
            )

            # Set access protections -> PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
            [UInt32]$lpflOldProtect = 0
            $CallResult = [Kernel32]::VirtualProtectEx($hProcess, $lpBaseAddress, $dwSize, 0x40, [ref]$lpflOldProtect)

            # Create replacement struct
            $UnicodeObject = New-Object UNICODE_STRING
            $UnicodeObject_Buffer = $data
            [UInt16]$UnicodeObject.Length = $UnicodeObject_Buffer.Length*2
            [UInt16]$UnicodeObject.MaximumLength = $UnicodeObject.Length+1
            [IntPtr]$UnicodeObject.Buffer = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::StringToHGlobalUni($UnicodeObject_Buffer)
            [IntPtr]$InMemoryStruct = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal($dwSize)
            [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::StructureToPtr($UnicodeObject, $InMemoryStruct, $true)

            # Overwrite PEB UNICODE_STRING struct
            [UInt32]$lpNumberOfBytesWritten = 0
            $CallResult = [Kernel32]::WriteProcessMemory($hProcess, $lpBaseAddress, $InMemoryStruct, $dwSize, [ref]$lpNumberOfBytesWritten)

            # Free $InMemoryStruct
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($InMemoryStruct)
        }

        # Process Basic Information
        $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION = New-Object _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
        $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_Size = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)
        $returnLength = New-Object Int
        $CallResult = [Ntdll]::NtQueryInformationProcess($ProcHandle, 0, [ref]$PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION_Size, [ref]$returnLength)

        # PID & PEB address
        echo "`n[?] PID $($PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.UniqueProcessId)"
        if ($x32Architecture) {
            echo "[+] PebBaseAddress: 0x$("{0:X8}" -f $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.PebBaseAddress.ToInt32())"
        } else {
            echo "[+] PebBaseAddress: 0x$("{0:X16}" -f $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.PebBaseAddress.ToInt64())"
        }

        # Lazy PEB parsing
        $_PEB = New-Object _PEB
        $_PEB = $_PEB.GetType()
        $BufferOffset = $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.PebBaseAddress.ToInt64()
        $NewIntPtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $BufferOffset
        $PEBFlags = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($NewIntPtr, [type]$_PEB)

        # Take ownership of PEB
        # Not sure this is strictly necessary but why not!
        if ($x32Architecture) {
            [Ntdll]::RtlEnterCriticalSection($PEBFlags.FastPebLock32)
        } else {
            [Ntdll]::RtlEnterCriticalSection($PEBFlags.FastPebLock64)
        } echo "[!] RtlEnterCriticalSection --> &Peb->FastPebLock"

        # &Peb->ProcessParameters->ImagePathName/CommandLine
        if ($x32Architecture) {
            # Offset to &Peb->ProcessParameters
            $PROCESS_PARAMETERS = $PEBFlags.ProcessParameters32.ToInt64()
            # x86 UNICODE_STRING struct's --> Size 8-bytes = (UInt16*2)+IntPtr
            [UInt32]$StructSize = 8
            $ImagePathName = $PROCESS_PARAMETERS + 0x38
            $CommandLine = $PROCESS_PARAMETERS + 0x40
        } else {
            # Offset to &Peb->ProcessParameters
            $PROCESS_PARAMETERS = $PEBFlags.ProcessParameters64.ToInt64()
            # x64 UNICODE_STRING struct's --> Size 16-bytes = (UInt16*2)+IntPtr
            [UInt32]$StructSize = 16
            $ImagePathName = $PROCESS_PARAMETERS + 0x60
            $CommandLine = $PROCESS_PARAMETERS + 0x70
        }

        # Overwrite PEB struct
        # Can easily be extended to other UNICODE_STRING structs in _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS(/or in general)
        $ImagePathNamePtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $ImagePathName
        $CommandLinePtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $CommandLine
        if ($x32Architecture) {
            echo "[>] Overwriting &Peb->ProcessParameters.ImagePathName: 0x$("{0:X8}" -f $ImagePathName)"
            echo "[>] Overwriting &Peb->ProcessParameters.CommandLine: 0x$("{0:X8}" -f $CommandLine)"
        } else {
            echo "[>] Overwriting &Peb->ProcessParameters.ImagePathName: 0x$("{0:X16}" -f $ImagePathName)"
            echo "[>] Overwriting &Peb->ProcessParameters.CommandLine: 0x$("{0:X16}" -f $CommandLine)"
        }
        Emit-UNICODE_STRING -hProcess $ProcHandle -lpBaseAddress $ImagePathNamePtr -dwSize $StructSize -data $BinPath
        Emit-UNICODE_STRING -hProcess $ProcHandle -lpBaseAddress $CommandLinePtr -dwSize $StructSize -data $BinPath

        # &Peb->Ldr
        $_PEB_LDR_DATA = New-Object _PEB_LDR_DATA
        $_PEB_LDR_DATA = $_PEB_LDR_DATA.GetType()
        if ($x32Architecture) {
            $BufferOffset = $PEBFlags.Ldr32.ToInt64()
        } else {
            $BufferOffset = $PEBFlags.Ldr64.ToInt64()
        }
        $NewIntPtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $BufferOffset
        $LDRFlags = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($NewIntPtr, [type]$_PEB_LDR_DATA)

        # &Peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList->Flink
        $_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY = New-Object _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY
        $_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY = $_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.GetType()
        $BufferOffset = $LDRFlags.InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink.ToInt64()
        $NewIntPtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $BufferOffset

        # Traverse doubly linked list
        # &Peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList->InLoadOrderLinks->Flink
        # This is probably overkill, powershell.exe should always be the first entry for InLoadOrderLinks
        echo "[?] Traversing &Peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList doubly linked list"
        while ($ListIndex -ne $LDRFlags.InLoadOrderModuleList.Blink) {
            $LDREntry = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStructure($NewIntPtr, [type]$_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)

            if ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($LDREntry.FullDllName.Buffer) -like "*powershell.exe*") {

                if ($x32Architecture) {
                    # x86 UNICODE_STRING struct's --> Size 8-bytes = (UInt16*2)+IntPtr
                    [UInt32]$StructSize = 8
                    $FullDllName = $BufferOffset + 0x24
                    $BaseDllName = $BufferOffset + 0x2C
                } else {
                    # x64 UNICODE_STRING struct's --> Size 16-bytes = (UInt16*2)+IntPtr
                    [UInt32]$StructSize = 16
                    $FullDllName = $BufferOffset + 0x48
                    $BaseDllName = $BufferOffset + 0x58
                }

                # Overwrite _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY struct
                # Can easily be extended to other UNICODE_STRING structs in _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY(/or in general)
                $FullDllNamePtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $FullDllName
                $BaseDllNamePtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $BaseDllName
                if ($x32Architecture) {
                    echo "[>] Overwriting _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.FullDllName: 0x$("{0:X8}" -f $FullDllName)"
                    echo "[>] Overwriting _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.BaseDllName: 0x$("{0:X8}" -f $BaseDllName)"
                } else {
                    echo "[>] Overwriting _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.FullDllName: 0x$("{0:X16}" -f $FullDllName)"
                    echo "[>] Overwriting _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.BaseDllName: 0x$("{0:X16}" -f $BaseDllName)"
                }
                Emit-UNICODE_STRING -hProcess $ProcHandle -lpBaseAddress $FullDllNamePtr -dwSize $StructSize -data $BinPath
                Emit-UNICODE_STRING -hProcess $ProcHandle -lpBaseAddress $BaseDllNamePtr -dwSize $StructSize -data $BinPath
            }

            $ListIndex = $BufferOffset = $LDREntry.InLoadOrderLinks.Flink.ToInt64()
            $NewIntPtr = New-Object System.Intptr -ArgumentList $BufferOffset
        }

        # Release ownership of PEB
        if ($x32Architecture) {
            [Ntdll]::RtlLeaveCriticalSection($PEBFlags.FastPebLock32)
        } else {
            [Ntdll]::RtlLeaveCriticalSection($PEBFlags.FastPebLock64)
        } echo "[!] RtlLeaveCriticalSection --> &Peb->FastPebLock`n"
    }

    Masquerade-PEB -BinPath "explorer.exe"


    PinToTaskbar 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk'
    #UnpinFromTaskbar "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe"

    PinToStartmenu 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk'
    #UnpinFromStartmenu "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe"

    # Verify here C:\Users\Px_Install\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu
    # and here C:\Users\Px_Install\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Output is

```
[?] PID 4904
[+] PebBaseAddress: 0x00000026120AD000
[!] RtlEnterCriticalSection --> &Peb->FastPebLock
[>] Overwriting &Peb->ProcessParameters.ImagePathName: 0x0000013771C41950
[>] Overwriting &Peb->ProcessParameters.CommandLine: 0x0000013771C41960
[?] Traversing &Peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList doubly linked list
[>] Overwriting _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.FullDllName: 0x0000013771C42418
[>] Overwriting _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.BaseDllName: 0x0000013771C42428
[!] RtlLeaveCriticalSection --> &Peb->FastPebLock

Method [taskbarpin] executed for [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk]
Method [startpin] executed for [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk]
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\x_PS Dev>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error record?

Comment: And, just verified that the Pin to Taskbar code works correctly in Windows 10 pre Anniversary Update. So the question is, does AU close the "hole" that Masquerade-PEB takes advantage of?

Comment: Hopefully it was closed: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141230-00/?p=43273 with link to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673 - but Raymond Chen's style of Microsoft out of fashion, and who knows if that's still current thought.

Comment: Well, closed with a Group Policy mechanism to allow for our own automation to work would be ideal. I understand the frustration with developers using it as a marketing tool, but when it's closed in a way where a firm's Technology Managers can't use it as a way to advertise newly installed software, for example, it's a real problem. It feels as if Microsoft has thrown the baby out with the bathwater. Then again, Microsoft blocked the ability to put LNKs, even LNKs to network resources, in an email, even an email to someone else in the domain. Knee jerk reactions are rarely a good solution. :(